# Testing an array of object in Junit, but import can not be resolved

Tags: junit, junit4

I am trying to test if my `insert` function works. But Eclipse is giving me an import error. I have junit4 in my built path.
[image: JunitTest]

Here is my Solution class

```
public class Solution {

    public class Interval {
        int start;
        int end;
        Interval() { start = 0; end = 0; };
        Interval(int s, int e) { start = s; end = e; };
    }

    public static ArrayList<Interval> insert(ArrayList<Interval> intervals, Interval newInterval) {
        // more code
```

Here is my SolutionTest class

```
import Solution.Interval; // Error: The import Solution can't be resolved

public class SolutionTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ArrayList<Interval> er = new ArrayList<Interval>(); //imoprt Interval
        System.out.println("Start");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem would go away if you **put your code in a package** other than the default package. The compiler probably thinks that `Solution` is a package, and cannot find a class or interface named `Interval` in the `Solution` package.

Also, if you want to be able to create `Interval` without a `Solution`, **change `Interval` from an inner class to a nested class**:

```
package solution;

public class Solution {

    public static class Interval {
        private final int start;
        private final int end;

        public Interval() {
          this(0, 0);
        }

        public Interval(int start, int end) {
          this.start = start;
          this.end = end;
        }

        ...
    }

    public static ArrayList<Interval> insert(List<Interval> intervals, Interval newInterval) {
      ...
    }
}
```

The above class would be in "src/solution/Solution.java"

Here is the test:

```
package solution;

import solution.Solution.Interval;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class SolutionTest {
  private final List<Interval> emptyIntervalList = new ArrayList<Interval>();

  ...
}
```

You could, of course, make `Interval` a top-level class, but if you do I highly recommend putting it in a different file (named Interval.java).

I also recommend using [the standard Maven directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Comment: Very detailed response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the import statement 
//import Solution.Interval;

and try as below

ArrayList er = new ArrayList();

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can you please clarify how your answer helps? I need to test an a list of user-defined objects. Without the `Interval` class, it's just like testing a normal list which is no use for me.

Comment: Sorry for the late response & for  my answer that didn't give you exact output. I intend to put below statement.
ArrayList<Solution.Interval> er = new ArrayList<Solution.Interval>();  
But there occurred a problem in copy paste which I didn't notice at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own question. I separate the `Interval` class into its own class. And that solved the issue.

So instead of:

```
public class Solution {

    private static class Interval {
        int start;
        int end;
        Interval() { start = 0; end = 0; };
        Interval(int s, int e) { start = s; end = e; };
    }
```

I did this:

```
public class Solution {
    // some code here
}

class Interval {
    int start;
    int end;
    Interval() { start = 0; end = 0; };
    Interval(int s, int e) { start = s; end = e; };
}
```

I think the problem was `Interval` was a nested class and you can't directly test nested class in Junit. But if anyone knows a more detailed explanation, please share.

Comment: You can import and test nested classes. Note that `Interval` is an *inner class*, not a nested class. To make it a nested class, make `Interval` static